# Set Focus on the first error field JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2

How do you set input focus on the first field that has an error?

The [code from BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/set-focus-in-jsf.html) works fine. However, `setHighlight()` and `setFocus()` are in a file rather than each xhtml page:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   setHighlight('${highlight}');
   setFocus('${focus}');
    });
```

This results in passing `${highlight}` to `setHighlight()` method rather than the element id.

Comment: What's the concrete problem you're having with it? It sounds like as you haven't tried it at all.

Comment: @BalusC: Can we perform set focus functionality on xhtml page instead of the jsp page?                                            // Set ${focus} and ${highlight} in JSP.
        facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("focus", focus);
        facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("highlight", highlight.toString());

Comment: We're not interested in answering yes-no questions. What exactly have you tried and how exactly did it fail for you?

Answer (score 0):

JSF doesn't resolve EL in JavaScript files. So you really need to declare them inline. If you do it in the master Facelets template, then you don't need to duplicate it over all template clients.

```
<h:outputScript target="body">
    setHighlight('${highlight}');
    setFocus('${focus}');
</h:outputScript>
```